# How to show assignment statement and function call at the same time in a flowchart?

Tags: flowchart

There are different symbols for statements (processes) and function calls in flowcharts. When I have a statement which assigns the return value of a function to a variable, how can I show it in a flowchart? Should I show it as a process or a function (i.e. a plain rectangle or a rectangle with stripes)?

q = myFunction(x,y);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Flowchart Symbols Defined](https://www.breezetree.com/articles/excel-flowchart-shapes/):

> A Predefined Process symbol is a marker for another process step or series of process flow steps that are formally defined elsewhere. This shape commonly depicts sub-processes (or subroutines in programming flowcharts). If the sub-process is considered "known" but not actually defined in a process procedure, work instruction, or some other process flowchart or documentation, then it is best not to use this symbol since it implies a formally defined process.

Given

> q = myFunction(x,y);

Use a *Predefined Process* symbol, if `myFunction` is formally defined elsewhere; otherwise use a *Process* symbol.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Actually, this is an assignment statement involving a defined subroutine call. Although, assignment statements are usually shown with Process symbol in flowcharts, it seems more logical to use  Predefined Process symbol in this case to emphasize the existence of a defined subroutine call.